# javascript recursive object unordered list keep same index for parent

Tags: javascript, loops, object

In this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/18obnr9L/)** you can see the red `<b>` tags are showing a different index from the black ones below, this happens why I am trying to use the same index for both `<li>` and parents `<ul>`, but something is not working properly... it seems like, only at the very first step, the index counting in skipped and all the remaining index then is "slipped" one step forward, so they are not matching...

```
var object = {
    sometdhing: {
        sometfhing: {
            somgething: 'text',
            someathing: 'text'
        },
        someathing: {
            somefthing: 'text',
            sometghing: 'text'
        }
    },
    someathing: {
        somethfing: {
            somgething: 'text',
            somethihng: 'text'
        },
        somejthing: {
            somethhing: 'text',
            somfething: 'text'
        }
    }
}


var indexes = [];
var object2ul = function (data, level) {
    var keys = Object.keys(data);
    var json = '<ul>'+ '<b style="color:red">'+level+'</b>';
    for (var i=0; i<keys.length; ++i) {

        var key = keys[i];
        indexes.push(i);
        json += '<li>' + "<b>" + indexes.join('_') + "</b> - " + key;
        if (typeof(data[key]) === 'object') {
            json += object2ul(data[key], indexes.join('_'));
        } else {
            json += '<ul><li>' + data[key] + "</li></ul>";
        }
        json += "</li>";
        indexes.pop();
    }
    return json + "</ul>";
}

document.body.innerHTML = object2ul(object, 0);
```

Please help...

Comment: you can do this indexing with just css also, is that ok

Comment: @MuhammadUmer I really doubt the css can help me with it xD

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the result to be?

Comment: css has counters which can help with numbering

Answer (score 0):

Css did help

[Code: http://jsfiddle.net/18obnr9L/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/18obnr9L/2/)

here i construct elements from object like `ul, li, ol`...

```
var data = {
    sometdhing: {
        sometfhing: {
            somgething: 'atext1',
            someathing: 'atext2'
        },
        someathing: {
            somefthing: 'atexta1',
            sometghing: 'atexta2'
        }
    },
    someathing: {
        somethfing: {
            somgething: 'btext1',
            somethihng: 'btext2'
        },
        somejthing: {
            somethhing: 'btexta1',
            somfething: 'btexta2'
        }
    }
};

list(data);

function list(data) {
    var ul = document.createElement('ol'),
        li = document.createElement('li')
        main = ul.cloneNode();

        getProps(main, data);
        document.body.appendChild(main);

    function getProps(parent, d) {
        for (var i in d) {
            if (typeof d[i] == "string") {
                addLi(parent, d[i], i);
            } else if (d[i] instanceof Object) {
                var pli = addLi(parent, '', i);
                var temp = ul.cloneNode();
                getProps( temp, d[i] )
                pli.appendChild(temp);
                parent.appendChild(pli);
            }
        }
    }
    function createUli(val){
        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
        var l = li.cloneNode();
        ul.appendChild(l);
        l.innerText = val;
        return ul;
    }
    function addLi(p, val, i) {
        var ele = li.cloneNode();
        ele.innerText = i;
        if (val != '') ele.appendChild(createUli(val));
        p.appendChild(ele);
        return ele;
    }
}
```